# I'm using Workbench. what is Rest API Configuration?

Tags: ant, jbpm, workbench, kie, kie-workbench

I installed Workbench from jbpm-installer-full-7.1.0.Final.zip using ANT install.demo. Then i start it using ANT start.demo.
i import repository  "https://github.com/kiegroup/jbpm-playground".
What is the configuration should i do to use rest api and start process?
i tried this but it faild "http://localhost:8080/kie-server/services/rest/server/containers/human-resources_1.0/processes/hiring/start". Thannks

Answer (score 0):

you only need to build and deploy. you don't need to configure anything. once it is deployed.

check the documentation 
{server}:{port}/kie-server/docs

so in your case, 
localhost:8080/kie-server/docs